# Set higher Drawable resolution for big images

Tags: android, xml, imageview, scale, android-drawable

I have in my project a list of PNG icons in many scales (mdpi at 32px, hdpi at 48px, xhdpi at 64px and xxhdpi at 96px, automatically created by Android Studio), and I get one Activity where I want to display this icons in two distinct sizes, some bigger than the others.

Problem is that the bigger ones (the only ones where I really define layout widths and heights) use low res versions of the drawable instead of nicer ones.

Here is my XML code:

```
<!-- small icon -->
<ImageView 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_like" />
<!-- ... -->
<!-- big icon -->
<ImageView 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_like"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp" />
```

And here is the result:

[image: Screenshot of the two ImageViews from the emulator]

As for a comparison, here's the xxhdpi version of PNG of the Drawable, clearly better than the big one I got.

[image: xxhdpi version of the Drawable]

I'm new to Android, so I suppose I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot figure what. Should I define higher res pictures per resolution? Should I provide an `ic_icon_like` and an `ic_icon_like_big` for the two displayed versions?

Comment: Try using `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in bigger image view.

Comment: Tried it and nope, it just gives me the same blurry thumb, a bit distorted though.

Comment: In fact, I'm wondering if I should not define drawables with bigger sizes in my res folder (something like 250px for xxhdpi); the sizes generated by Android Studio are for "action bar and tab icons", which is not really my case.

Comment: You can try here https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: Are you placing the generated images in their respective folders? Example: `ic_icon_like_hdpi.png` shoud be in `drawable-hdpi` folder under `res`

Comment: Under my res/ folder, there are folders like drawable/, drawable-hdpi/, drawable-mdpi/, ... with at each time the right version of the PNG in it. Seems okay to me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally moved on and used a webfont instead, as I get all my icons in SVG formats.

Sizing and coloring are way simpler like this.

So I added an `/app/assets/fonts/webfont.ttf` file in my project, created an `IconView` heriting from `TextView` like this:

```java
public class IconView extends TextView {
    public IconView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // here I trully use a cache, but remove it for a full example
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/webfont.ttf"));
        // the following allows me to use a default color if no 'textColor' attribute is provided
        int[] set = {android.R.attr.textColor};
        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, set);
        ColorDrawable color = (ColorDrawable) attributes.getDrawable(0);
        attributes.recycle();    
        if (color == null) {
            this.setTextColor(MY_DEFAULT_COLOR);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I added constants in `strings.xml` for each icon in my webfont, as:

```
<string name="icon_like">&#xe635;</string>
```

And used the whole in my XML activities and fragments like this:

```
<com.mySociety.myProject.IconView android:text="@string/icon_like" />
```